# Dynamic lists in 3 column having layout issues

Tags: html, css

hye,i am working on simple jsp in which created some order list in HTML in three column 
but my problem is that if there is list have more items are comes in 3rd column the next list with is placed in first column is leave relevant space between upper list.for more information view below image.

[image]

```
<ul class="ulClass">
<li class="liclass">
<ul class="subul">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
</ul>
</li>
<li class="liclass">
<ul class="subul">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
</ul>
</li>
<li class="liclass">
<ul class="subul">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
</ul>
</li>
<li class="liclass">
<ul class="subul">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
<li class="subli">
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

and css for main ul and li is

```
.ulClass {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 12px !important;
    padding-top: 20px !important;
    width: 935px;
}
.ulClass li {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 12px !important;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 32%;
}
```

Comment: post your html or create fiddle for us